# Where can I get drivers for Windows 8

Tags: drivers, windows-8

I own a Dell Inspiron 1545, which came pre-installed with Vista. I upgraded to 7, and Dell made special windows 7 drivers available. I cannot seem to find any such special driver downloads for Windows 8.

Is there any place I can check for driver updates, and be notified if and when they become available.

The required drivers include:
  - Webcam
  - Alps Touchpad
  - Broadcom Wifi

Of these, the webcam and wifi default windows drivers are working fine. However the touchpad configuration needs the official drivers.

Comment: All you can do is wait until an update is released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver models of Windows 7 and 8 are mostly the same (with just a few minor upgrades here and there). So Windows 7 drivers should work just fine on Windows 8 as well. Unless they come with an installer that checks for a specific Windows version (e.g. N-trig's DuoSense drivers did this which made it a pain to install).

Answer (score 1):

The best place to check for driver is always the manufacturer's website. If the driver you need is not in there, you're out of luck.

You can always try to install the old drivers in Windows 8 under compability mode, but that's not recommended